# Complex data indexing with Lucene?

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

So I need to search a database of boxes. Each box can contain multiple items. Each box has a general description and each item has a description along with some descriptor/value pairs (ie, size:large). I want to be able to search this database using a similar set of information- I'm looking for a box like x, holding a, b, and c items. Return the box that contains the most similar items.

However, I'm confused about how I should go about indexing this data in Lucene. I know that I can index multiple values to a single field by overriding the getPositionIncrement() method of the analyzer, but how do I link descriptors to a specific item? For example, I may have 2 items in my box:

```
Item 1
description: pair of shoes
color: blue

Item 2
description: Jacket
color: red
```

and I search for

```
Item A
description: pair of shoes
color: red

Item B
description: Jacket
color: blue
```

to my knowledge, it will return the box with item 1 and 2 as a match. But I want the color to only apply to that specific item, and I need to be able to search a box to match multiple items simultaneously to find the most similar box.

The reason I'm using Lucene is because this is a regular search job that occurs on a regular basis, but it isn't live, so a search server like Solr is not needed because searches only occur in narrow windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to store relation between parent document (box) and child documents (items). Fortunately there is BlockJoinQuery for such purposes. This [article](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html) describes it in details for Lucene 3.x or you can use [ToParentBlockJoinQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/ToParentBlockJoinQuery.html) which is available for Lucene 4.x